# foursquare api get category id from category name

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, foursquare

I'm trying to make an app with using foursquare api. There will be a textfield and user will type category name. So I need to get category id with this name. But I didn't find any endpoint. How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you can add this mapping statically: https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree

Comment: try for yourself first, if you have an issue with your code then came back here. just search on google for "foursquare api document"

Comment: There is no endpoint you are looking for. Sample code here: https://gist.github.com/koogawa/31d8d7ca757d7961fbc5f8c2fea8aa78

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the response from the [venues/categories endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories) and search for the category id you need.